# Converting Facebook Connect to Application

Tags: facebook, facebook-application

I currently operate a site which uses the Facebook Connect for log-in. 
I would like to "convert" this site to a facebook appliation (that is, to be used as an iframe in Facebook website).
What will be the best way to do so? What changes do I need to make in the log-in procedure to enable it? 
Is there anyway I can use the same URL of my site to be served as the facebook app, and in that way avoid duplication of content (one for the website version and the other one for the app)?

Joel

Answer (score 2):

I strongly advise you to visit the facebook developer links and see all the information there.

There is a lot more to consider then to just turn your website into a facebook app.

The size and fluidity will be the first issue, as your site may not render correctly in facebook's iframe.

It may also be that you need to host the app on facebook's servers, which I cannot confirm but their developer site will.